# Problems building with typescript transpiler (TSC) using the --build flag

Tags: typescript, amd

I am receiving `Error: Debug Failure. False expression` when trying to run a build using the --build flag.

I copied all the files/patterns from the typescript project, except I set the "module" to "amd" in tsconfig-base.json, but otherwise it is a subset of what you'll find in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src (only tsc & compiler, both simplified).

You can find the source here:

https://github.com/ca0v/speech-lab/blob/so_2019_q1/tsconfig.json

But when I attempt to transpile it, I get the error:

```
ca0v@ca0v-PC MINGW64 /h/code/ca0v/speech-lab (master)
$ npm run build

> speech-lab@1.0.0 build H:\code\ca0v\speech-lab
> tsc -b

H:\code\ca0v\speech-lab\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:1362
            throw e;
            ^

Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
    at mergeSymbol (H:\code\ca0v\speech-lab\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:26088:26)
    at H:\code\ca0v\speech-lab\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:26187:47
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at mergeSymbolTable (H:\code\ca0v\speech-lab\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:26185:20)
    at initializeTypeChecker (H:\code\ca0v\speech-lab\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:49309:21)
    at Object.createTypeChecker (H:\code\ca0v\speech-lab\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:25950:9)
    at Object.getTypeChecker (H:\code\ca0v\speech-lab\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:72860:79)
    at getReferencedFiles (H:\code\ca0v\speech-lab\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:74290:43)
    at Object.create (H:\code\ca0v\speech-lab\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:74329:41)
    at createBuilderProgramState (H:\code\ca0v\speech-lab\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:74572:37)
```

The last version of TSC I tried was ^3.4.0-dev.20190323.

QUESTION: Anyone have a way to build multiple AMD layers using a composite build?

Comment: First of all, I think you should be using ```outDir``` instead of ```"outFile": "../built/local/tsc.js",```
Using outFile is susceptible to runtime errors https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html

Comment: That's a very old comment from basarat and I've build several projects that build in the proper order very quickly and generate .map files for easy analysis.  I think circular references can still cause problems.

Comment: Submitted https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30591